# Maximum number of dbprocesses already allocated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm running a Delphi application that uses BDE for database connection. Ocassionally (more often than I'd like) this error pops up when opening a query.

Googling for this error, most picks refer to MS SQLServer database, and speak about a `dbsetmaxprocs` function, which I can't seem to find.

So the question is: how can I prevent/correct this error? On which situations does this error rise and how can I avoid/work around it?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I leave some links I followed for reference.

- *Keep getting error: "Maximum number of DBPROCESSES already allocated".*
  http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28718
  tried that, didn't work.
- _SQL Error 10029 - Maximum number of DBPROCESSes already allocated
  http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Miscellaneous/Q_20843695.html
  can't find unclosed connections in my code.
- *BUG: dbprocerrhandle Does Not Get Fired For Error 10029*
  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/q164/1/71.asp&NoWebContent=1&NoWebContent=1
  can't find `dbsetmaxprocs` anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The error is BDE error unrelated to SQL Server. There is no point in raising the number of max connections, you're just going to hit the new max again. The solution is to fix your code and stop leaking connections.

Comment: This is probably what's happening. This problem is happening at client's testing environment, but not at production environment. And we've been unable to reproduce it here (through it had happenned sometimes here too, we haven't been able to define the steps needed to reproduce). So since we cannot reproduce, we cannot trace and find the leak at the moment. I'll surely update when we come to a solution. Thanks!